# Mongoose Typescript find method on ref field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am trying to find all users which are part of a particular organization. For that, I have two models:

Organization

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { updateIfCurrentPlugin } from 'mongoose-update-if-current';

/**
 * An interface that describes the properties
 * that are required to create a new Organization
 */
interface OrganizationAttrs {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

/**
 * An interface that describes the properties
 * that a Organization model has
 */
interface OrganizationModel extends mongoose.Model<OrganizationDoc> {
  build(attrs: OrganizationAttrs): OrganizationDoc;
}

/**
 * An interface that describes the properties
 * that a Organization Document has
 */
export interface OrganizationDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string;
  version: number;
}

const organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      transform(_doc, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
      },
    },
  }
);

organizationSchema.set('versionKey', 'version');
organizationSchema.plugin(updateIfCurrentPlugin);

organizationSchema.statics.findByEvent = (event: {
  id: string;
  version: number;
}) => {
  return Organization.findOne({
    _id: event.id,
    version: event.version - 1,
  });
};

organizationSchema.statics.build = (attrs: OrganizationAttrs) => {
  return new Organization({
    _id: attrs.id,
    name: attrs.name,
  });
};

const Organization = mongoose.model<OrganizationDoc, OrganizationModel>(
  'Organization',
  organizationSchema
);

export { Organization };
```

And users

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Password } from '../services/password-service';
import { RoleDoc } from './role';
import { OrganizationDoc } from './organization';

/**
 * An interface that describes the properties
 * that are required to create a new User
 */
interface UserAttrs {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  password: string;
  organization: OrganizationDoc;
}

/**
 * An interface that describes the properties
 * that a User model has
 */
interface UserModel extends mongoose.Model<UserDoc> {
  build(attrs: UserAttrs): UserDoc;
}

/**
 * An interface that describes the properties
 * that a User Document has
 */
interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  active: boolean;
  password: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  organization: OrganizationDoc;
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    organization: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Organization',
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      transform(_doc, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.password;
        delete ret.__v;
      },
    },
  }
);

userSchema.pre('save', async function (done) {
  if (this.isModified('password')) {
    const hashed = await Password.toHash(this.get('password'));
    this.set('password', hashed);
    this.set('updatedAt', Date.now);
  }
  done();
});

userSchema.statics.build = (attrs: UserAttrs) => {
  return new User(attrs);
};


const User = mongoose.model<UserDoc, UserModel>('User', userSchema);

export { User };
```

If I add a new user, I don't get any trouble:

```js
// Create an organization
  const organization = Organization.build({
    id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString(),
    name: 'Organization One',
  });
  await organization.save();
  
  const password = 'MySuperPassword';
  // Create a user 
  let user = User.build({
    email: 'test@organization-one.com',
    firstName: 'organization-one firstname',
    lastName: 'organization-one lastname',
    password: password,
    organization: organization.id, // Adding user to organization (link it actually)
  });
  await user.save();
```

What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve all users with a particular organization id, if I do:

```js
router.get(
  '/:organizationId/users',
  requireAuth,
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  const organizationId = req.params.organizationId;

  const users = await User.find({ organization: organizationId });

  res.status(200).send(users);
  }
);
```

I have tried with `await User.find({ organization: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(organizationId) });` with no luck...

Edit

the only thing that worked (which does not look pretty clean) is to cast organizationId as Object

```js
const organizationId = req.params.organizationId as Object;
```

Is there another way to do it ? Or should I retrieve the organization from db in this particular case ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use **Typegoose** when writing **Typescript**, but since **Typegoose** is just a wrapper for **Mongoose**, I think the following statement can help you too:

```
const users = await User.findById(organizationId);
```

Comment: I am going to then search for one user with an organizationId which is wrong as far as I know